# XeLaTeX + mathtools + unicode-math missing symbols `\Coloneqq` and `\models`

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math, mathtools

Sorry, but I am browsing since morning around and try to find a solution for that issue. I have a `beamer` presentation with `moloch` theme and want to use the `Fira` font but only for the `mathcal` part I want to use the font `TeX Gyre Pagella Math`. This part seems to work but in `mathtools` I want to also use the symbols for `\Coloneqq` as well as `\models`. These I cannot make work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont[range=cal]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
test lawkejf aweijf awelfj a

$\varphi\Coloneqq x,\mathcal F, \Sigma\models \pi$
\end{document}
```

Yields the following:

[image: screenshot from compilation]

I also tried something like `\setmathfont[range={\models,\Coloneqq}]{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}` but this also does not work. I am lost. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Could you update your title to something that will help future users with the same problem to find your post?

Comment: @ Arne Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the symbols are not in your fonts, so you must take them from somewhere else. E.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont[range=cal]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range={"22A7,"2A74}]{GFS Neohellenic Math}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Fira Math} %just in case, reset math parameters

\begin{document}
test lawkejf aweijf awelfj a

$\varphi\Coloneqq x,\mathcal F, \Sigma\models \pi$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get Package fontspec Error: The font "GFS Neohellenic Math" cannot be found. Is that a standard font?

Comment: it is in a current texlive. But you can use `albatross U+2A74` and `albatross U+22A7` to search for some other font in your system.

Comment: This is super weird, albratross lists several fonts that are compatible, even your suggestion as well, but when I compile I get the message that the font cannot be found.

Comment: does it work with lualatex?

Comment: Just was about to write that it works with lualatex ;-) Thanks. You have an idea why it is not working with xelatex?

Comment: well my guess would be that you have a linux system and that doesn't find fonts by font name in the texmf trees.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152055/discussion-between-arne-and-ulrike-fischer).